# Дипломный проект на тему "Создание сетевого хранилища данных на базе одноплатного компьютера"

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Пишу дипломный проект заканчиваю колледж и выбрал тему создание сетевого хранилища.

1. Сейчас я выбираю между Raspberry Pi 4 и Repka Pi(российская разработка, созданная по форм фактору Raspberry Pi 3)
   https://repka-pi.ru/comparison - сайт сравнения.
   Repka Pi дешевле к тому же собирается в России, но поскольку у неё малое сообщество и на её базе сделано мало проектов. Посоветуй те что выбрать
2. Можно ли переносить проекты написанные для Raspberry Pi на Repka Pi, и смогу ли я воспользоваться уже разработанными программами для Raspberry Pi для Repka Pi

Comment: Сейчас здесь два вопроса. В свою очередь ответ на первый вопрос будет основан на мнении разных людей. [ask].

Comment: "Хранилище данных" как-то подразумевает некоторую избыточность, в моём понимании. Избыточность подключения к сети, резервирование по питанию, резервирование подключения дискового массива, избыточность самого дискового массива... А у указанных вами, извините, PCIe-то не выведен, куда вы собираетесь Fibre Channel подключать? А флешка с гигабитным ethernet на слово "хранилище" не тянет, даже на уровне дипломного проекта.

Answer (score 8):

1. Если нужно дешевле, то есть ещё китайская Orange Pi - почти в 2 раза дешевле Репки. Но так как проект сетевого хранилища, то поищите другие платы. Рекомендую смотреть в первую очередь на те в которых есть sata или sata в m2 разъёме подключенная к шине проца, а не usb. Глянь Banana Pi Berry.
2. Проект такого типа переносимый. Почти без изменений. Но на разных платах нужны будут разные сборки операционной системы.